# Java Enumeration of Musical Notes

Tags: java, enums

How would you create an enumeration of the musical notes in Java, with each notes having an octave and then a keyed variable? This is what I have so far...

```
    public enum Notes
    {
            c,
            cS,
            d,
            dS,
            e,
            f,
            fS,
            g,
            gS,
            a,
            aS,
            b;
            int octave;
            boolean isPlaying;
    }
```

So when I access the enums in my code I write something like this...

```
Notes.c.octave = 4;
Notes.c.isPlaying = true;
```

Now here is my question: How can I have an isPlaying boolean for each note in each octave?

Like so:

```
Notes.c.octave.isPlaying = true;
```

Or would I have to go like:

```
public enum Notes
{
        c1,
        cS1,
        d1,
        dS1,
        e1,
        f1,
        fS1,
        g1,
        gS1,
        a1,
        aS1,
        b1
        c2,
        cS2,
        d2,
        dS2,
        e2,
        f2,
        fS2,
        g2,
        gS2,
        a2,
        aS2,
        b2;

        etc...

        boolean isPlaying;
}
```

Thank you in advance for taking your time to answer this question!

Answer (score 5):

**You should not modify the fields of your enum!!!**

The reason is that each instance is unique in the JVM (like a singleton), and another thread using the same note will be sharing the same `playing` field, which is a seriously wrong design.

Also, your enum should be named singular `Note`, not plural `Notes`. The reason should be obvious: Each instance of the enum represents a single note, not multiple notes.

The right way to do it would be to create a class that has 3 fields:

```
public class Tone {
    private Note note; 
    private int octave;
    private boolean playing;
    // with getters and setters
}
```

---

Since every note can be flat ♭, sharp ♯, double-flat 𝄫 and double-sharp 𝄪, I would use this model which more accurately reflects reality. Also, even the `playing` field feels wrong. It feels more like `Tone` should be [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable) and some other entity (eg `Player`) knows what `Tones` are currently playing, so I'd recommend this:

```
public enum Note {
    C, D, E, F, G, A, B
}

public enum Shift {
    DoubleFlat, Flat, Natural, Sharp, DoubleSharp
}

public class Tone {
    private Note note; 
    private Shift shift; 
    private int octave;
    private int duration; // include a duration - perhaps milliseconds
    // with only getters, being immutable
}

public class Player {
    // has references to `Tones` and a way to schedule their being played
}
```

Comment: Yes my code is kind of ugly lol... thank you for pointing that out. I guess I found out you could do some cool things with enumerations and tried taking it as far as I could. But yes thank you for the digital slap back into java reality xD jkjk. I might implement this structure so thank you!

Comment: _C sharp_ and _D flat_ are the same note (just as _D sharp_ is the same as _E flat_ and so on). If the purpose of the program is to create audio music, they should probably be represented by the same object internally. If the idea is to represent written music, it would be good to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Manufaktura.Music library: http://manufaktura-programow.pl/En

It contains object model for steps, pitches, rhythmic values, musical scales, etc. It's in c#, but the syntax is similar to Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would move to an object rather than an enum. You could make an object JavaNote that has:
String note;
int octave;
boolean isPlaying;

Why bother with enums?

Comment: Agreed ... and for easy lookup, you could put each JavaNote instance in a map that you can access using the note's name.

Comment: Hashmaps would be fast - key off the string Note and the object as the value.

Comment: I believe it should be a class _MusicNote_ that has a _Note_ instance, which is an enum.  This way you could only allow valid notes and maintain Set of notes that have state.

Comment: ^^ Thank you for the suggestions I will give them a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create the enum elements with default `octave` variable as `0` and `isPlaying` variable as `false` as below:

```
  public enum Notes
  {
        c(0, false),
        cS(0, false),
        d(0, false),
        dS(0, false),
        e(0, false),
        f(0, false),
        fS(0, false),
        g(0, false),
        gS(0, false),
        a(0, false),
        aS(0, false),
        b(0, false);
        int octave;
        boolean isPlaying;

        Notes(int octave, boolean isPlaying){
            this.octave = octave;
            this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
        }

        int getOctave(){
            return this.octave;
        }

        boolean isPlaying(){
            return this.isPlaying;
        }
   }
```

Now you may use the enums as :

```
Notes.a.octave = 5;//assign the value if required
Notes.a.isPlaying = true;//assign the value if required
System.out.println(Notes.a.octave);//this will print 5
System.out.println(Notes.a.getOctave());//this will print 5
System.out.println(Notes.a.isPlaying);//this will print true
System.out.println(Notes.a.isPlaying());//this will print true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This completely defies enum purpose.

Comment: @AmitD: How? When you want to use ENUMs with some int values corresponding to them, this is how you do it e.g. MIN(0), MAX(10) etc, which mean MIN will correspond to 0 and MAX will correspond to 10. I have seen several instances of such usage. `If it defies the purpose, it won't have been supported this long.`

Comment: Now it is not immutable it has state.

Comment: @Amit: Refer this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html from Oracle. Looks at `Planet` Enum example.

Comment: It is not issue with the constructor the issue is what you are doing after that changing values inside enum

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `isPlaying` flag get rid of that just store instance of `Notes` instance and check for it.

```
Notes playingNote = Notes.c1;
```

when you have to check for playing note

```
 playingNote == Notes.c1
```

What you only need to change is the constructor. Declare constructor which takes Octave value.

```
c1(1);
private int octave = 0;
private Notes(int octave){
        this.octave= octave;
}
```

*Note: Assuming that Octave for musical instruments does not change. Not an expert in musical instruments though.For multiple notes at the same time you can use EnumSet*

Comment: Yup, enums should immutable... so keep the immutable stuff in the enum, and shift the state out to a class which has-a instance of the enum next its current state.

Comment: Multiple notes can be played at the same time.

Comment: As I stated above I don't usually use enums and I decided to see if I could fit them into my Synthesizer Program. I'm pretty new to java still if you couldn't tell, hence why I asked the question. But Thank you because this actually made me realize I didn't need the isPlaying flag. I only tried to implement it because when I held down a key it would play the note repeatedly which may be because I am using the keyPressed method and not keyTyped? I'm not sure i'll go look that up. Oh the other reason I used the isPlaying is for drawing the whether a Key was pressed or not.

Comment: Thank You! This saved me a headache :D Great community Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Crupler Welcome. You can always accept the best answer by clicking on right arrow. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question!

I believe you have the first part correct:

```
/** An enum of the valid note names */

public enum Note {
    c,
    cS,
    d,
    dS,
    e,
    f,
    fS,
    g,
    gS,
    a,
    aS,
    b;
}
```

You should create a class that has private *octave* and *isPlaying* properties and an instance of your *Note* enum.

Maybe you would end up with code like this:

```
class InstrumentNote {
    private Note note;
    private int octave = 0;
    private boolean isPlyaing = false;

    public InstrumentNote(Note someNote, int someOctave) {
        note = someNote;
        octave = someOctave;
        isPlaying = false;
    }
}

class TestIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int octaveCount = 8; // big piano
        Set<Note> instrumentNotes = buildInstrument(octaveCount);
    }

    /** 
     *  Creates a Set of Notes.  A Set is used because each instrument
     *  should consist of a group of unique note instances, based on how
     *  many octaves it has.
     */

    public static Set<InstrumentNote> buildInstrument(int numOctaves) {
        Set<InstrumentNote> noteSet = new TreeSet<InstrumentNote>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOctaves; i++) {
            for (Note n : Note.values()) {
               noteSet.add(new InstrumentNote(n, i, false));
            }
        }
        return noteSet;
    }


}
```

It'sa good question whether or not octave should be part of the enum.

The octave of a note should not change... But I think it fits better as a private member of a class that also has a Note instance.

Since I'm not sure of your requirements, I'm trying to imagine them...

I envision that you might create either an *instrument* or a *song* from a group of valid notes (shown above).

This would allow you all kinds of flexibility:

- you could create an abstarct Instrument class that has a Set of notes
- you could implement different kinds of Instruments (a Trumpet can only play one note at a time, a piano can play many)
- you could implement a song, which is a series of notes that have durations, volumes, styles (staccato, legato), etc...

---

If you want to do some of the above, you'll also want a way to sort your notes (so a Set of notes can be ordered).

You could do this with a Comparator and/or maybe an enum property named *index* or *order* (or something).

I'll leave the exercise of writing a [*NoteComparator*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) up to you.

I'm not sure if you can make an enum implement the interface [*Comparable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)...

Hope some of this is accurate or helpful...

Comment: Oh wow thank you for the very detailed post @jahroy . I will look all of this helpful information over and see what fits my Synthesizer program :D 

Much Appreciated 
 -Kyle